# Python unittesting: Test whether two angles are almost equal

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I want to test a function that outputs a heading in degrees, which is a number in the interval [0, 360). Since the result is a floating-point number, comparing the actual result against the expected with `unittest.assertEqual()` does not work. `unittest.assertAlmostEqual()` is better since it provides a tolerance. This approach works for heading that are not close to 0 degrees.

Question: What is the correct way to test for headings whose expected value is 0 degrees? `assertAlmostEquals()` would only include angles that are slightly larger than 0 degrees, but would miss those that are slightly smaller than 0, i.e. 360 degrees...

Comment: Define your own helper function that takes two angles and returns abs of the difference

Comment: Whenever you're comparing floating point numbers, you have to include an 'epsilon', a small number below which things are considered for all intent and purposes to be zero. Ex: 1E-6 or 1E-8 etc. `a == b if abs(a - b) <= epsilon`. Things get tricky if both values approach 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the squared Euclidian distance between two points on the unit circle and the law of cosines to get the absolute difference between two angles:

```
from math import sin, cos, acos
from unittest import assertAlmostEqual        

def assertAlmostEqualAngles(x, y, **kwargs):
    c2 = (sin(x)-sin(y))**2 + (cos(x)-cos(y))**2
    angle_diff = acos((2.0 - c2)/2.0) # a = b = 1
    assertAlmostEqual(angle_diff, 0.0, **kwargs)
```

This works with radians. If the angle is in degrees, you must do a conversion:

```
from math import sin, cos, acos, radians, degrees
from unittest import assertAlmostEqual        

def assertAlmostEqualAngles(x, y, **kwargs):
    x,y = radians(x),radians(y)
    c2 = (sin(x)-sin(y))**2 + (cos(x)-cos(y))**2
    angle_diff = degrees(acos((2.0 - c2)/2.0))
    assertAlmostEqual(angle_diff, 0.0, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I don't think this preserves differences between angles very well.

Comment: @SturlaMolden The concept works with two modifications: (1) When comparing the results of sin and cos, one should set a tolerance; I ended up using `delta=0.001`. (2) If the input is provided in degrees, one has to convert it to radians with `x = math.radians(x)`.

Comment: I have added a numerical correction using law of cosines and also **kwargs to pass keyword arguments places, msg and delta to assertAlmostEqual.

Comment: You must in any case adjust delta to the tolerance of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same situation, and found a much, much simpler solution, by taking advantage of modulo computation:

```
In [20]: def d(a, b):
    ...:     c = (b - a) % 360
    ...:     if c > 180:
    ...:         c -= 360
    ...:     return c
    ...:

In [21]: d(1, 3)
Out[21]: 2

In [22]: d(1, 358)
Out[22]: -3
```